# Detect built-in normal style at cursor in Word using VSTO VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

To make a context-sensitive toolbar (buttons that are activated only if the cursor is on certain styles of paragraphs), I want to determine if the paragraph at the cursor is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal` (which is a constant of value of -1). My code needs to work even if the user's default style is "Normal" in some other language than English. The variants of the paragraph style names can be found [here](http://www.thedoctools.com/downloads/DocTools_List_Of_Built-in_Style_English_Danish_German_French.pdf).

[Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074581/get-localized-unlocalized-style-names-in-word-vsto) that seems to imply it's not possible to get style information without it being a string.

I have code to find the current style name as a string:

```
Private Function getSelectionStyle() As String
    Return CType(Globals.ThisDocument.Application.Selection.Paragraphs.Style, Word.Style).NameLocal
End Function
```

How can I get the integer value to compare it with `WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal` (the language-independent style value of Normal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply compare with the Normal style instance from the collection of styles in your document:

```
Public Function IsNormalStyle(ByVal style As style, ByVal Document As Document) As Boolean

    Dim normalStyle As style = document.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal)
    Return normalStyle = style

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to document.Styles(index). Your answer is far from compilable, but I got it to work with
    `Dim normalStyle As Style = Globals.ThisDocument.ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal)

Dim selectionStyle As Style = CType(Globals.ThisDocument.Application.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Style, Word.Style)
    
Return selectionStyle.NameLocal.Equals(normalStyle.NameLocal)`